# Loud, low-frequency "booming" sound in car

Tags: everyday-life, acoustics, pressure, air

I drive a Scion XD, and I've noticed that whenever I drive at about 40mi/hr or so with just the back windows rolled down, I get a loud "booming" effect at roughly 10Hz. What causes this? I assume it has something to do with air pressure "bouncing" back and forth in the car.

I can try to sketch the interior, if needed.

Comment: I'm not quite sure it is - "noise" is rather vague, and for me the "booming" happens even with two windows rolled down (whereas OP in the linked question suggest it only happens with just one window down).

Comment: The answer is going to be exactly the same though: acoustic resonance.

Comment: You're sitting inside a large flute.  10Hz makes it subsonic but still uncomfortable.  Just crack a front window, or roll one of the back ones partway up!